# Optimum way to get a single best unique match of two pandas dataframe columns, based on a set of parameters present in both dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, fuzzywuzzy, difflib, rapidfuzz

I would like to **fuzzy match two Pandas dataframes** based on a **number n parameters in columns**, all present in both dataframes. The output should be a pair of unique filenames. The parameter sets might not be unique and could be duplicates. There should be a minimum threshold of string similarity.

**Dataframe 1:**

```
    FILENAME       PARAMETER1    PARAMETER2    PARAMETER3    PARAMETER4    
1   xyz111.txt     3.82          Rock          No            red
2   abc222.txt     14.20         Tree          Yes           green
3   def999.txt     6.91          House         Yes           yellow
4   uvw567.txt     2.11          Car           No            green
5   asd222.txt     13.90         Ball          Yes           blue
...
```

**Dataframe 2:**

```
    FILENAME       PARAMETER1    PARAMETER2    PARAMETER3    PARAMETER4    
1   stv999.txt     12.17         Car           Yes           red
2   hij888.txt     5.64          Tree          No            red
3   klh123.txt     7.21          House         No            green
4   qrs543.txt     3.20          Car           No            green
5   lmn111.txt     17.17         House         Yes           yellow
...
```

The preferred output should be the filename and exactly one unique matched filename like this:

**Preferred output:**

```
    FILENAME       FILENAME_MATCHED    
1   xyz111.txt     hij888.txt        
2   abc222.txt     stv999.txt       
3   def999.txt     klh123.txt      
4   uvw567.txt     None    
5   asd222.txt     lmn111.txt
...
```

I was able to do fuzzy matching with different libraries like "FuzzyWuzzy" or "rapidfuzz" etc. by combining the parameters into a new string column. Still I am having a hard time to deal with duplicates in the matched filenames, as the parameter sets might not be unique, but the filenames are.